# Laravel foreach in if statement

Tags: laravel

This is my code

```
@if ($story)
    <table class="table-auto my-3 w-full">
        <thead class="justify-between">
            <tr class="bg-gray-800">
                <th class="px-16 py-2">
                    <span class="text-gray-300">#Id</span>
                </th>
                <th class="px-16 py-2">
                    <span class="text-gray-300">Name</span>
                </th>
                <th class="px-16 py-2">
                    <span class="text-gray-300">Description</span>
                </th>
                <th class="px-16 py-2">
                    <span class="text-gray-300">Actions</span>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="bg-gray-200">
            @foreach ($story as $item)
                <tr class="bg-white border-4 border-gray-200">
                    <td class="px-16 py-2 flex flex-row items-center">
                        {{ $item->id }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ Str::words($item->name, 3, $end = '...') }}
                    </td>
                    <td class="px-16 py-2">
                        {!! Str::words($item->description, 6, $end = '...') !!}
                    </td>
                    <td class="px-16 py-2">
                        <a href="{{ route('dashboard.story.edit', $item->id) }}">
                            <button class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-1 border rounded-md hover:bg-white hover:border-blue-500 hover:text-black">
                                Edit
                            </button>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
@else
    <p>No results found</p>
@endif
```

This is my controller

```
public function index()
{
    $story = Story::paginate(10);
    return view('admin.story.index', ['story' => $story]);
}
```

I'm using Laravel 8 and I don't want to show table headers when the value is null. Laravel showing tables headers and not showing the 'No results found' message.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use @if (count((array)$story))

Comment: Sorry same results showing

Comment: can you show controller code

Comment: I've edited the qeustion

Comment: use @if($story->total())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use paginate, your data split. so if you want check this data empty or not just use

```
@if( $story->total() )
```

just replace it with

```
@if ( $story )
```